# WCF Failed to add a service error

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2012

I am a beginner in web services.
I tried to open a new WCF client project in VS 2012.
I am working by this tutorial: 
http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page1.htm#comment-949587244
just after opening a new project I tried to run the debugger and I get this error:

Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.

Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from htt://localhost:15021/Service1.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.

Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I tried searching the internet for this error but because I am new to this I can't find the resolution to the problem.
what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: 
I tried to open a project with .net Framework 4.0 and it worked fine
so the problem is with .net Framework 3.5
but I need to work with 3.5

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about underlying error however you can try to check following:

1) Check if WCF service is running and you are able to access it using a browser

2) Check if you have provided correct authentication details in WCF service web.config.

Please check if you have provided correct data under identity section, userPrincipalName

3) Under behaviours section,

Please enable serviceMetaData httpGetEnabled="true"

Under Visual Studio you can use WCF Service Configuration Editor to verify all these values.

You can access this tool from Tools menu.

Comment: I managed to find out that the problem is that my project is made for .net framework 3.5. but I need this framework so how can I work with it?

Comment: I am not sure if what issue causing this error.Any specific reason you are trying to address .Net framework 3.5?

Comment: because the tutorial is addressing this framework and because the web service i'm using supports only this framework